# PHP get key value from array

Tags: php

When I put `print_r($data);` I get the following

```
Array
(
    [name] => Cheese
)
```

Is there a way to get the key `name` in a variable on its own?

There may be occasions that `name` could be `email` and other values.

Comment: `key()` or `list($key, $val) = each($data);`

Comment: expect more from people with 3k rep , just saying.

Comment: Maybe he's just messing? Lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
var_dump(array_keys($data));
```

> Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you know the value but you don't know the key? If so you could write something like this:

```
$array = ['name' => 'Cheese'];
array_flip($array);
var_export($array['Cheese']); // Output: name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the array key extracted to their own variables using the `extract` function. For example

```
$a = array("color"=>"blue");
extract($a);
echo $color;
```